# Separating chunks of code using commented line

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to separate my code using commented line to make them more readable like below:

```r
# ----------------- reading data -------------------
df = cars

# ----------------- data Summary -------------------
summary(df)
```

just wondering if such an approach is common among experts to add something like titles in their scripts and whether there is a shortcut key to produce such lines: ------------
instead of repeatedly tapping on the - key?

Comment: Have you considered using Rmarkdown https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com ?

Comment: This question is probably off topic as it is too opinion based. As it happens, I use this set-up in my own code because I find it makes the code more readable. You can implement it as a code snippet in R studio - see [here](https://dcl-workflow.stanford.edu/rstudio-snippets.html) for a how-to

Answer (score 1):

A cool thing with RStudio is that you can do navigable sections:

```
# reading data ####
df = cars

# data Summary ####
summary(df)
```

[image]

You have to start with `#` and to finish with at least 4 `#` (or maybe this works too with 4 identical symbols).

Comment: I use the trick per @StephaneLaurent. The document outline in your script files can then also be accessed (Ctrl+Shift+O)